# Help, can't call another class's method

Tags: iphone, class, methods, sdk

Tried many ways based on other questions asked here but could not get a method call to another class to compile.

I'm writing a dedicated class to process arithmetic, for example class Arithmetic.  It has no class variables.  It subclasses no class (though I tried NSObject with failure).  It will have methods of the type:

```
+ (NSString *)calculateEnergy:(NSString *)weight;
```

that I want to call from another class, in a static-method way, like:

```
self.label.text=[arithmetic calculateEnergy:@"8.0"];
```

where 'Arithmetic *arithmetic' is declared and given a retain property (synthesised etc.) in the header and implementation of the class wanting to access the calculateEnergy method.

I've tried various suggestions, such as variations on:

```
[(Arithmetic *) arithmetic calculateEnergy:@"8.0"];
```

every time getting an "Accessing unknown 'calculateEnergy' getter method"

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: What "failure" did you see when you tried to make this class a subclass of NSObject?

Comment: If someone managed to give you a good answer, you should kindly accept their answer.

Comment: @SK9: Haven't yet had a chance to run the suggestions - I unfortunately have to borrow a macbook to do my coding. Will hopefully get access tonight.  Very much looking forward to testing them and accepting or commenting back - thank you so much for everyone's help!

Comment: @Firoze: 'failure' just meant it didn't make a difference if I subclassed NSObject or not - it didn't show a difference in what I was doing.  I'm eager to try the below answers and see if they solve the problem.

Comment: If need be I recommend you buy a cheap second hand Mac to code on, it doesn't need to be powerful. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I don't have the complete picture, your method definition is for a class-level, static method, as opposed to an instance method. You would want to call it as

```
self.label.text = [Arithmetic calculateEnergy:@"8.0"];
```

You also would not need to create an instance of `Arithmetic` to call the method you have there.

Answer (score 0):

Is `arithmetic` not an instance of `Arithmetic`? If instead you try `self.label.text=[Arithmetic calculateEnergy:@"8.0"];` you should be OK.